# Javascript Sound Start/Stop and Image Change

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, audio

I am new to JS and I have a pretty simple-seeming problem.

I want to have a small image that when clicked changes to a different image and at the same time begins playing a looped sound file.  When the image is clicked a second time it changes back to the original image and also stops the sound file.

You can think of it as a button that says "start".  when "start" is clicked it loops the sound and changes to "stop" and when "stop" is clicked it goes back to start and the sound ceases playing.

I've gotten as far as creating none-displayed checkbox inside of a label which is a square that when checked plays sound and when unchecked stops sound.  Problem is I can't get the checkbox to change into different images with "check", "uncheck".

I've also got some code that has a link change images, but I cannot figure out how to make it play the sound.

SO basically i need to combine these two things.  BUT I CAN'T figure out how.  And I've been googling for the past two days nonstop but cannot find a clearcut and simple answer.

It may help to know that I plan on having many of these small clickable images on the same page, so the Javascript needs to be able to be light but effect all of the links or divs or whatever they are in the end.

Sorry for such a long question.  Anybody?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any code that you could share? It would make it easier for us to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var pos = 0
            var sId = 'sound';

            function change() {
                if(pos == 0) {
                    pos = 1;
                    document.getElementById('btn').src="http://www.buzzingup.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/stop.png";

                    var e = document.createElement('embed');
                    e.setAttribute('src','beep.mp3');
                    e.setAttribute('id',sId);
                    e.setAttribute('hidden','true');
                    e.setAttribute('autostart','true');
                    e.setAttribute('loop','true');

                    document.body.appendChild(e);
                } else {
                    pos = 0;
                    document.getElementById('btn').src="http://geekoffices.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/start-button-300x299.png";
                    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById(sId));
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://geekoffices.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/start-button-300x299.png" onClick="change()" id="btn" />
    </body>
</html>
```

How about that, I think it should work.

**Edit:**
Here is an OO version that should do what you need:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function imageSwitch(_imgID,_imgStart,_imgStop,_soundFile) {
                this.imgID = _imgID;
                this.imgStart = _imgStart;
                this.imgStop = _imgStop;
                this.soundFile = _soundFile;

                this.pos = 0;
                this.e;

                this.change = function() {
                    if(this.pos == 0) {
                        this.pos = 1;
                        document.getElementById(this.imgID).src = this.imgStop;

                        this.e = document.createElement('embed');
                        this.e.setAttribute('src',this.soundFile);
                        this.e.setAttribute('id','sound'+this.imgID);
                        this.e.setAttribute('hidden','true');
                        this.e.setAttribute('autostart','true');
                        this.e.setAttribute('loop','true');

                        document.body.appendChild(this.e);
                    } else {
                        this.pos = 0;
                        document.getElementById(this.imgID).src = this.imgStart;
                        this.e.parentNode.removeChild(this.e);
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var abc = new imageSwitch('btn1','http://geekoffices.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/start-button-300x299.png','http://www.buzzingup.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/stop.png','beep.mp3');
            var def = new imageSwitch('btn2','http://geekoffices.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/start-button-300x299.png','http://www.buzzingup.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/stop.png','beep.mp3');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://geekoffices.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/start-button-300x299.png" onClick="abc.change()" id="btn1" />
        <img src="http://geekoffices.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/start-button-300x299.png" onClick="def.change()" id="btn2" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks chief - this works perfectly for an application involving 1 image and i appreciate your working it out for me.  i'll go through the code line by line so i can really understand what's going on here.

Comment: sorry meant, to add to my response but apparently the return key means add comment, rather than new paragraph (new to stack o)... anyway, for my application i am trying to do multiple images on the same page that all embody this "change()" but are all different, i.e. different sound files, different images.  is there a compact way to write the javascript to accomplish this easily?  again i appreciate your response and think you are awesome.  i might just go ahead and have many of the same function or try to figure something else out on my own.  thanks again!

Comment: an update - i basically just copied the function and changed a few attributes, i.e. function() --> functionb(), 'btn' ---> 'btnb', and so on.  in the end i'm looking to use about 40-50 of these on the page so the code will be pretty bloated, but it does the job.  and the site probably won't go live, more of an experiment so shouldn't be too big a problem.

Comment: Check my edit. I have written a new bit of code that should do what you need.

Comment: @Chief17 If I have a lot of buttons that play different sound. How can I make one button that control all start/stop sound?