# Javascript Sound Start/Stop and Image Change Part2

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I want to have a small image that when clicked plays a sound and changes to a different image. When the button is then clicked again it changes back to previous image ans stops the sound.

You can think of it as a button that says "start". when "start" is clicked it loops the sound and changes to "stop" and when "stop" is clicked it goes back to start and the sound ceases playing.

I tried using this code and it works perfectly for the images, but i can not seem to get the different sounds to play for the 2 images.

[Javascript Sound Start/Stop and Image Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333021/javascript-sound-start-stop-and-image-change)

I also found seperate code to play and stop sound with this script:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
    var playing = false;

    $('a#button').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("down");

        if (playing == false) {
            document.getElementById('player').play();
            playing = true;
            $(this).text("stop sound");

        } else {
            document.getElementById('player').pause();
            playing = false;
            $(this).text("restart sound");
        }


    });
});
  </script>

<div>
<a id="button">play sound</a> 
                <audio id="player" src="mysound.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Which also works...

Can I combine the 2 together? Or am I not using the first javascript code correctly?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to play a sound and change the image and vice versa, the following would work just fine:

**HTML**

```
<p>
   <a href="#" id="button"> <i class="fa fa-play fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</p>
<audio id="player" src="http://soundbible.com/mp3/kids-record-player-daniel_simon.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

**JS**

```
  var playing = false;

  $('#button').click(function() {

    if (playing == false) {
      document.getElementById('player').play();
      playing = true;
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-play');
      $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-pause');

    } else {
      document.getElementById('player').pause();
      playing = false;
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-pause');
      $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-play');
    }

  });
```

The idea is basically this: If the sound is playing, then swap classes. This example could be expanded to toggling the hide and show of images.

Refer to [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/Rtd1hQ05LuFQnTyiAy5n?p=preview) working example.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

> f I would want to use this for more than one image on the same webpage. Do I just add more add & remove classes? Or do I make a new function for every image?

Actually you can use that function for any number of images. We just need to generalize a few things and we are good to go.

The first thing I did was to change the jQuery selector for the click event. Previously we searched specifically for the element with the unique id `#button`. In order to bind to multiple buttons, I gave them the same name: `$('[name=button]')`.

The variable `playing` helped us keep track whether or not the user played the button. In order to control whether or not the button was clicked, I had to move the variable `playing` to the `audio` element as an attribute. This way every audio element "knows" its current state (playing or paused);

**HTML**

```
 <audio name="player" src="http://soundbible.com/mp3/kids-record-player-daniel_simon.mp3" preload="auto" data-playing="false"></audio>
```

*Notice the data-playing="false" attribute*

**JS**

```
    var $button = $(this), // get the button
        $player = $button.next('[name=player]'); // button and player are siblings

    if ($player.data('playing') == false) {
      $player[0].play();
      $player.data('playing', true);
      ...

    } else {
      $player[0].pause();
      $player.data('playing', false);
      ...
    }
```

*The trick here is to update the playing attribute to ensure we know the user clicked play or pause*

Please refer to [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/JaTjqD5AADpnewazGO21?p=preview) updated version of the previous example.

Comment: Thanks you very much n0m4d for helping meout.

Comment: If I would want to use this for more than one image on the same webpage. Do I just add more add & remove classes? Or do I make a new function for every image?

Comment: @Niné please check the edit where I explain some strategies to generalize the function. By the way, I see you're new to SO. If you feel this answer solved the problem, please consider marking it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark =)

Comment: Ok, will look in to that further. Thank you for your help n0m4d.